Add a path in file browser through pywinauto
I'm just a noob using pywinauto through Spyder for the first time. I'm trying to automate a desktop app, step by step and I got stuck when a file browser opened to request a file path and file name as shown below (I apologize, my first language is Spanish, hopefully it is understandable:
File browser default path
I was using the .print_control_identifiers() property and the path directory field is a Toolbar, identified as Toolbar4. Indeed, I am able to select that item/field by different methods: single click, right click then "Edit Adress". But the problem is that I cannot edit the toolbar to add the path where the file that needs to be uploaded is. I tried using the .wrapper_object() and .set_edit_text() methods but apperently they do no work on Toolbar objects. I was looking at different alternatives here in this website but did not work.
app.window(best_match='Importar archivo', top_level_only=True).child_window(best_match='Toolbar4', control_type="Toolbar").type_keys(r"C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Documentos\Automatizacion de Swiss Manager")

and
app.window(best_match='Importar archivo', top_level_only=True).child_window(best_match='Toolbar4').set_text(r"C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Documentos\Automatizacion de Swiss Manager")

Expected outcome:
File with new path

Probably you need to focus on file address bar, for example, using .click_input() method. But maybe setting text to bottom edit box for "File path:" should also work, it may work without additional .click_input() since this edit box is already enabled. Full path is typically OK for this edit box.

Thank you. I may understand that the .click_input() method would work to select or click the address bar. I was able to do so but I do not know how to input the correct file path upon that.

Please provide more details about which path you try and which path is actually typed. Maybe you forgot raw string like r"C:\Program Files\...\some_file.txt" which doesn't treat backslash as an escape sequence. But it is general Python question not relevant to pywinauto only. If it is something else, please edit your question with details.
